# How to properly upload to s3 with nextjs/node/ts

Tags: node.js, typescript, amazon-s3, next.js

I've been trying for a while now to upload a simply image to s3. There's so much info out there, a lot of it outdated and so I'm here to ask simply, how do you upload a simple image to s3 using ts/nextjs/node. I have an IAM user, I have the credentials, everything I need, here's all the relevant code I have and it returns a response but nothing's uploaded to the bucket.

```
  const [selectedFile, setSelectedFile] = useState<any>(null);

  const handleFileUpload = (e: React.FormEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    setSelectedFile(e.currentTarget.files?.[0]);
  };

  const onSubmit: SubmitHandler<RegisterFormSchemaType> = async (data) => {
    const s3 = new AWS.S3({
      accessKeyId: process.env.S3_ACCESS_KEY as string,
      secretAccessKey: process.env.S3_SECRET_KEY as string,
    });

    const uploadedImage = await s3.upload({
      Bucket: *bucketname*,
      Key: "test",
      Body: selectedFile,
    });

    console.log(uploadedImage);

  };
```

And my input html:

```
   <Input type="file" onChange={handleFileUpload} />
```

Apparently, this way is deprecated and I also read about presignedurls and what-not, I'm just so confused and want to know how to do it once and for all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its not recommended to use AWS SDK on the browser-side to upload images using AWS credentials as it would make your credentials vulnerable to MITM attacks that target credential grabbing.

What I would recommend instead is the combination of the following steps:

1. For local debugging, use AWS credentials to provide required permissions to your debugging machine. For an application deployed on the cloud, please assign an IAM role to your compute layer so it could upload objects to the S3 bucket without providing explicit credentials on the codebase.
2. Build a backend-based API that will generate a [pre-signed URL](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/developer/generate-presigned-url-modular-aws-sdk-javascript/) that you have to return to the browser-based portion of your application.
3. The pre-signed URL will then be sent over to the client side and used by the client-side application to upload the image directly to S3 from the end-user's browser.

This is considered to be a more secure and efficient solution because it helps you limit the potential attack time (tnx to URL expiry time) and blast surface (Upload is limited to a single object) related to maliciously uploaded files to the bucket.

Here is a [link](https://betterprogramming.pub/how-to-upload-files-to-amazon-s3-from-nextjs-app-b7ef1909976b) that you could follow to implement your version of it in a NextJS application.

Comment: Very informative answer and thanks for the link!

Comment: I've ran into an issue where the backend isn't recognizing what I'm sending it. I get an empty object on the backend